# How to call express-validator from middleware function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, express-validator

I have been struggling to call `express-validator` function from a `middleware` function. I can see execution is happing to `express-validator` but nothing is validating. Below is the code snipped:

```
router.get("/v2/course/poc", Policy.hybridPolicy, V2manageCourse.validatePOC)
```

`Policy.js`

```
const { basicValidations } = require("../../utils/common");

class Policy {
    constructor(req, res, next) {
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
        this.next = next;
    }

    static hybridPolicy = async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            log.info("hybridPolicy check")

            await schema.validation(req, res)
            await schemaValidationCheck.validate(req, res);

            next();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("hybridPolicy: ", e)
            log.error("Error occured during hybrid policy check", e.message)
            return next(ApiError.unAuthorize(e.message));
        }
    }

}

module.exports = Policy
```

`schema.js`

```
const { body, query } = require("express-validator");

const validate = (method) => {
    switch (method) {
     case "getCourseById": {
            return [
                query("courseid")
                    .exists()
                    .isMongoId()
                    .withMessage("courseid must be mongoId")
                    .not()
                    .isEmpty()
                    .withMessage("courseid can not be empty and must be a MongoId"),
            ];
        }
    }
}
module.export = {
  validate
}
```

`schemavalidationCheck.js`

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator')

const validate = async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    console.log(errors)
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    const extractedErrors = []
    errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ [err.param]: err.msg }))

    throw new Error({
        errors: extractedErrors,
    })
    // return next(res.status(422).json({
    //     errors: extractedErrors,
    // }))
}

module.exports = {
    validate
}
```

I use `return()` instead of `next()` in that because I wanted to check all the validations before calling `next()`.
Is there anybody have any idea why express-validator is failing to check?

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block, you should not call:

```js
next(ApiError.unAuthorize(e.message));
```

Rather:

```js
try {
   ...
} catch(e) {
   res.send(ApiError.unAuthorize(e.message));
   log.error("Error occured during hybrid policy check", e.message);
}
```

Or if you have an error catching middleware, you can simply do something like:

```js
try {
   ...
} catch(e) {
   throw new Error(ApiError.unAuthorize(e.message));
}
```

and in your error middleware you can handle appropriately. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html for refrence.